# Struts2 errors:The requested resource () is not available

Tags: struts2

Could you help me solve this problem. When I was trying to program the simple Struts2 HelloWorld program. It always has this error:The requested resource () is not available. Could you help me solve it?Thank you!

[image: jar Files]

### JSP File

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
hello world
</body>
</html>
```

### This is HelloWorld.java

```
package com.test.action;

public class HelloWorld {
    public String execute()throws Exception
    {
        return "success";
    }
}
```

### struts.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
    "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
    "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">

    <struts>

        <package name="struts2" extends="struts-default">

            <action name="helloworld" class="com.test.action.HelloWorld">
                <result name="success">/helloworld.jsp</result>
            </action>


        </package>

    </struts>
```

### web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

### Exception

```
Nov 30, 2012 11:07:54 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: .:/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java
Nov 30, 2012 11:07:54 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:test' did not find a matching property.
Nov 30, 2012 11:07:54 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:Hibernate' did not find a matching property.
Nov 30, 2012 11:07:54 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:struts2' did not find a matching property.
Nov 30, 2012 11:07:54 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol init
INFO: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
Nov 30, 2012 11:07:54 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 1232 ms
Nov 30, 2012 11:07:54 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService start
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Nov 30, 2012 11:07:54 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.35
Nov 30, 2012 11:07:55 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext filterStart
SEVERE: Exception starting filter struts2
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1680)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:269)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.setFilterDef(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:422)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:115)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4072)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4726)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Nov 30, 2012 11:07:55 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Error filterStart
Nov 30, 2012 11:07:55 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Context [/struts2] startup failed due to previous errors
Nov 30, 2012 11:07:55 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start
INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
Nov 30, 2012 11:07:55 PM org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket init
INFO: JK: ajp13 listening on /0.0.0.0:8009
Nov 30, 2012 11:07:55 PM org.apache.jk.server.JkMain start
INFO: Jk running ID=0 time=0/64  config=null
Nov 30, 2012 11:07:55 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 821 ms
```

Comment: on a quick look does not seems anything wrong to me? try to rebuild your application and den run it.other way is to download sample applications from struts2 repo and run them.

Comment: How do you deploy your application? Does your war file has all jars?

Comment: Probably, when you are buidling the application it's not including Struts2-core jar file. Go and check war file.

Answer (score 0):

`<filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher<filter-class>` and remove the unwanted jar files.you keep only the following jar files in in lib folder

commons-logging-1.0.4.jar
freemarker-2.3.8.jar
ognl-2.6.11.jar
struts2-core-2.0.11.jar
xwork-2.0.4.jar.

Regards,
Nag kamma.